# Error:Invalid qualifier: Scale

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xamarin.winphone

I am just getting started with Xamarin. I am using Visual studio 2015 and Xamarin Forms (Portable) template to create the projects. Once I create the projects and do a build, I get the following errors in the MakePRI file from the WinPhone project. what am I missing?

Invalid qualifier: Scale
Initializing Index

Build Output

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  App1 -> C:\Projects\Random\App1\App1\App1\bin\Debug\App1.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App1.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: App1.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
3>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App1.WinPhone, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
5>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: App1.UWP, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
5>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
6>------ Rebuild All started: Project: App1.Windows, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
2>    Processing: C:\Projects\Random\App1\App1\App1.Droid\obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Forms.Platform\l
2>  ibrary_project_imports\res\values\strings.xml
2>  App1.Droid -> C:\Projects\Random\App1\App1\App1.Droid\bin\Debug\App1.Droid.dll
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
2>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
2>    Processing: C:\Projects\Random\App1\App1\App1.Droid\obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Forms.Platform\l
2>  ibrary_project_imports\res\values\strings.xml
4>  App1.WinPhone -> C:\Projects\Random\App1\App1\App1.WinPhone\bin\Debug\App1.WinPhone.exe
4>MakePri : error 0x80073b0a: Initializing Indexer
4>MakePRI : error 0xdef00042: Invalid qualifier: Scale
6>  App1.Windows -> C:\Projects\Random\App1\App1\App1.Windows\bin\Debug\App1.Windows.exe
========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Just tried the same on my end with a new Forms Portable project and did not get that error. You might want to change to diagnostic build output verbosity to see if you can get more info. Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity. Set that to Diagnostic to get more info in the build output.

Comment: I did a Verbose output. The output was almost 70000 lines. What am I looking for?

Comment: Search the log for errors and/or exceptions for starters.